# How to save and retrieve images in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a nodejs restapi. Using mongoose as mongodb client.How can i save and retrieve the file from the mongodb.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: how to do it using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save files to MongoDB unless you convert them to a string format such as Base64 which I wouldn’t recommend. You should use something like AWS S3 for that.

Comment: couldn't i can  save it as chunks